# Difference Quotients Evans

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, differential-equations

There is a theorem in Evans partial differential equation book as follows:

if  $u \in W^{1,p}(U)$ then for each compact $V$ in $U$ we have that:
 $ |D^hu|_{L^p(V)} \leq C |Du|_{L^p(U)} $
for all $ |h| < \frac{1}{2} dist(\partial U, V)$

now I have read the proof and its a simple theorem indeed but I have no idea why that factor 1/2 is given in theorem. It seems to me the same thing can be said for all $ |h| < dist(\partial U, V)$
Thanks